# How to handle CSRF tokens with React Relay

Tags: reactjs, react-native, csrf, react-relay

I am busy working on a React Native app which talks to a GraphQL api off a Django server.

In React Native I am using React Relay to try and process my GraphQL requests (following the guide found [here](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/network-layer.html)) but I am having 403 issues with my requests.

The response says `CSRF token missing or incorrect` and Im trying to figure out the best way to get this working.

I understand that I need to get a CSRF cookie token first then somehow pass that along with my GraphQL Post request but not having much luck. 
My current implementation of this is as follows...

```
fetch('http://' + ip + ':8000/sign-in/') 
    .then((response) => {
        const cookieHeader = response.headers.map["set-cookie"]; // This gets me a cookie response with a CSRF token
        fetch('http://' + ip + ':8000/graphql', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cookie': cookieHeader, // Try and pass the received cookie to my POST
            'XSRF-TOKEN': cookieHeader // Trying this as well
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            query: operation.text,
            variables,
          }),
        }).then(response => {
          console.log('RESPONSE', response) // Currently getting a 403
          return response.json()
        })
    })
```

But this still gets me a 403 error.

I can't seem to find much more information on how to approach this. Can anybody tell where I'm going wrong, or some suggestions on how to otherwise approach this?

(below is a snapshot of my API requests)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So managed to get it working with the following...

```
return getCsrfToken().then(csrfToken => {
    if (csrfToken == null) {
        console.log('CSRF NOT SET')
    }

    const url = 'http://' + ip + '/graphql'
    return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: operation.text,
                variables,
            }),
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('POST ERROR', error)
        })
});

function getCsrfToken() {
    var url = 'http://' + ip + '/graphql';
    return CookieManager.get(url).then(response => {
        return response.csrftoken;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this because this is the most specific question I found for troubleshooting CSRF with Relay for Django + GraphQL

I was getting a similar CSRF error response even though I was posting the CSRF token.  I had to add to the fetch headers to match the security settings of my Django backend. In this case I'm Relay in the browser so I get the CSRF token from a cookie.

I had already followed the Django docs for [CSRF with AJAX in cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax). Due to my security settings I had to add the "same-origin" credential. I'll label the few things I had to change from the Relay Quick Start tutorial

```
import { get as getCookie} from 'browser-cookies'

return fetch('/graphql/', { // Added the trailing slash here 
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: "same-origin", // Added this line
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'), // getting token from cookies
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: operation.text,
    variables,
  }),
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
});
```

And that's what fixed it for me.